Can I use “curriculum” to refer to the lesson plans I made for my students in my extra classes?
I looked up “curriculum” and the definition is “the subjects that are included in a course of study or taught in a school, college, etc.” I don’t teach at schools or colleges but I’m making lesson plans for my Maths extra classes by myself, can I call it “curriculum” as well? If not, what word should I use?

I don't think you can use curriculum like that. But why don't you want to use the expression you obviously know already? Just stick with lesson plans.

A curriculum is a broad plan of what you will teach and when.  So your curriculum might have "Pythagoras' theorem in term 1 of year 8. Trigonometry in term 2 of year 11"  It doesn't go in to the details of how you will teach Trigonometry or what you will do in each lesson.
Such details might be fleshed out in a "Scheme of Work" (Lesson 1: similar triangles, Lesson 2: Finding the tangent of an angle...) And your lesson plans have the greatest detail "Lesson 1: begin with 5 minute starter on fractions.  then 10 minutes taking notes ..."
